# How to a create custom field that is multi-line text or text area?

Tags: custom-fields, user-experience

I want to create a custom 'About Me' field  for a web  profile, but there doesn't appear to be anyway to make a text area or multi-line text custom field.

I know I can set the field length to allow users to enter plenty of text (currently set to 1000 characters), but the input box will still only be a single line.

Of course, in Webforms in Drupal, for example, I can set the length of the input box as well, but, again, still only a single line.

The problem, then, is not that the user can't enter the text I want them to, but that their experience of doing so is disconcerting and uncomfortable.  They can't see most of the text they've entered, which makes editing very difficult and frustrating.

I feel like there must be an obvious solution for this, but can't find it.

Thanks,
Lewis

Comment: If you [read the documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/4.7/organising-your-data/creating-custom-fields/), it says clearly under Custom Fields --> Type: *Note: a longer text box which allows multiple lines*.

Comment: Yes.  My apologies.  Not sure how I missed that.  Thanks.

Comment: No need for an apology, just offering a pointer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the 'Note' type of custom field to get a text area